# Saving runtime created table rows using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

I am new to PHP. I am working on a form which has a table with thee columns that is two textboxes and and one combo box. I used JavaScript for generating the table rows and the same to delete it.
I also referred one of your blogs for generating the rows. Now I am stuck on how to save the values from the the generated textbox to the MySQL database. Can anyone help me out? It would be a huge favor.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["username"])) {
    header("Location: unauthorize_access.php");
}

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {

        $length = count($_POST['testparameters']);

        for($i=0; $i< $length; $i++){
            $TestParameters=$_POST['testparameters'][$i];
            if(!empty($TestParameters)){
            $InsertQuery = "INSERT INTO color(name) VALUES('$TestParameters')";
            $result=mysql_query($InsertQuery) or die(mysql_error());
        }
        }
        if(!$InsertQuery)
        {
            die('Could not enter data:' . mysql_error());
            }
    }
?>





<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>Makhtab</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="form2/view.css" media="all">
                <script type="text/javascript" src="form2/view.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="form2/calendar.js"></script>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript"> 
                    <script type="text/javascript">

                            function deleteRow(row)
                            {
                            var i=row.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
                            document.getElementById('POITable').deleteRow(i);
                            }


                            function insRow()
                            {
                            console.log( 'hi');
                            var x=document.getElementById('POITable');
                            var new_row = x.rows[1].cloneNode(true);
                            var len = x.rows.length;
                            new_row.cells[0].innerHTML = len;

                            var inp1 = new_row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
                            inp1.id += len;
                            inp1.value = '';
                            var inp2 = new_row.cells[2].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
                            inp2.id += len;
                            inp2.value = '';
                            x.appendChild( new_row );
                            }
                </script>
                              <script type="text/javascript">

                            function deletezimRow(row)
                            {
                            var i=row.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
                            document.getElementById('zimtable').deleteRow(i);
                            }


                            function inszimRow()
                            {
                            console.log( 'hi');
                            var x=document.getElementById('zimtable');
                            var new_row = x.rows[1].cloneNode(true);
                            var len = x.rows.length;
                            new_row.cells[0].innerHTML = len;

                            var inp1 = new_row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
                            inp1.id += len;
                            inp1.value = '';
                            var inp2 = new_row.cells[2].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
                            inp2.id += len;
                            inp2.value = '';
                            x.appendChild( new_row );
                            }
                </script>
                                    <!--<style type="text/css" title="currentStyle">
                                        @import "tran/css/layout-styles.css";
                                        @import "tran/css/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.css";
                                    </style>-->
                <script  type="text/javascript" src="tran/js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
                <script  type="text/javascript" src="tran/js/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min.js"></script>

                <script  type="text/javascript" src="tran/js/jq-ac-script.js"></script>
                </head>
                <body id="main_body" >

                    <img id="top" src="form2/top.png" alt="">
                        <div id="form_container">

                            <h1><a>Untitled Form</a></h1>
                            <form id="makhtab" class="appnitro" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">
                                <div class="form_description">
                                    <h2>Makhtab Details</h2>
                                    <!--<p>This is your form description. Click here to edit.</p>-->
                                </div>                      
                                <table border="0px" width="100%">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><label class="description" for="element_1">Code</label></td><td><input id="element_1" name="code" class="element text small" type="text" maxlength="6" value=""/></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><label class="description" for="element_1">Name</label></td><td><input id="element_1" name="name" class="element text large" type="text" maxlength="40" value=""/> </td>
                                    </tr>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td><label class="description" for="element_1">Address</label></td><td><input id="element_4_1" name="add1" class="element text large" value="" type="text"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td></td><td><input id="element_4_1" name="add2" class="element text large" value="" type="text"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td></td><td><input id="element_4_1" name="add3" class="element text large" value="" type="text"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><label class="description" for="element_1">City</label></td><td><select name="cmbcity" class="element text medium" style="font-size:18px;"/>
                                            <option value=""></option>
                                            <?php
                                            mysql_connect("localhost", "root", '') or die(mysql_error());
                                            mysql_select_db("webapp") or die(mysql_error());
                                            $result = mysql_query("SELECT `name` from city ") or die(mysql_error());

                                            while ($year = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

                                                echo "<option value='$year[name]'>$year[name]</option>";
                                            }
                                            ?>
                        </select>

                                    </tr>
                                                                        <tr>
                                        <td><label class="description" for="element_1">State</label></td><td><select name="cmbstate" class="element text medium" style="font-size:18px;"/>
                                            <option value=""></option>
                                            <?php
                                            mysql_connect("localhost", "root", '') or die(mysql_error());
                                            mysql_select_db("webapp") or die(mysql_error());
                                            $result = mysql_query("SELECT `name` from state ") or die(mysql_error());

                                            while ($year = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

                                                echo "<option value='$year[name]'>$year[name]</option>";
                                            }
                                            ?>
                        </select>
                                                                        </tr>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><label class="description" for="element_1">Country</label></td><td><select name="cmbcountry" class="element text medium" style="font-size:18px;"/>
                                        <option value=""></option>
                                        <?php
                                        mysql_connect("localhost", "root", '') or die(mysql_error());
                                        mysql_select_db("webapp") or die(mysql_error());
                                        $result = mysql_query("SELECT `name` from country ") or die(mysql_error());

                                        while ($year = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

                                            echo "<option value='$year[name]'>$year[name]</option>";
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                        </select>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><label class="description" for="element_1">Telephone</label></td><td><input id="element_1" name="country" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><label class="description" for="element_1">Mobile</label></td><td><input id="element_1" name="country" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="10" value=""/></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <br />
                                    </tr>

                                    </table>

                                         <tr>
                                    <br /><p style="border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;"></p><br />
                                    <div class="form_description">
                                        <h2>Zimmedar Details</h2>
                                        <!--<p>This is your form description. Click here to edit.</p>-->
                                    </div>
                                </tr>
                                         <input type="button" id="addmorezimbutton" value="Add zimmedar" onclick="insRow()"/><br/><br/>
                                    <table id="zimtable" border="0px" size="100px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td width="10" align="center"><label class="description">Srno.&nbsp;</label></td>
                                            <td width="118"><label class="description">Zimmedar Name</label></td>
                                            <td width="118"><label class="description">Mobile</label></td>

                                            <td width="10"></td>
                                            <td width="10" align="center"></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>1</td>
                                            <td width="210"><input  size="40" maxlenght="40" type="text" id="zimame[]"/></td>
                                            <td width="80"><input  size="10" maxlenght="10" type="text" id="zimmob[]"/></td>

                                            <!--<td><input  size="45" maxlenght="10" type="text" id="momob"/>&nbsp;</td>-->
                                            <td><input type="button" id="addzimmore" value="+" onclick="inszimRow()"/></td>
                                            <td align="center"><input type="button" id="delzimbutton" value="-" onclick="deletezimRow(this)"/></td>
                                        </tr>

                                    </table>

                                                                         <tr>
                                    <br /><p style="border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;"></p><br />
                                    <div class="form_description">
                                        <h2>Muallim Details</h2>
                                        <!--<p>This is your form description. Click here to edit.</p>-->
                                    </div>
                                </tr>
                                         <input type="button" id="addmorePOIbutton" value="Add Muallims" onclick="insRow()"/><br/><br/>
                                    <table id="POITable" border="0px" size="100px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td width="10" align="center"><label class="description">Srno.&nbsp;</label></td>
                                            <td width="118"><label class="description">Moallim Name</label></td>
                                            <td width="118"><label class="description">Mobile</label></td>
                                            <td width="118"><label class="description">Qabiliyat</label></td>
                                            <td width="10"></td>
                                            <td width="10" align="center"></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>1</td>
                                            <td width="210"><input  size="40" maxlenght="40" type="text" id="moname[]"/></td>
                                            <td width="80"><input  size="10" maxlenght="10" type="text" id="momob[]"/></td>
                                            <td><select name="cmbmuallim[]" class="element text large" style="font-size:18px;"/>
                                                <option value=""></option>
                                                <?php
                                                mysql_connect("localhost", "root", '') or die(mysql_error());
                                                mysql_select_db("webapp") or die(mysql_error());
                                                $result = mysql_query("SELECT `name` from qabiliyat ") or die(mysql_error());

                                                while ($year = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

                                                    echo "<option value='$year[name]'>$year[name]</option>";
                                                }
                                                ?>
                                                </select></td>
                                            <!--<td><input  size="45" maxlenght="10" type="text" id="momob"/>&nbsp;</td>-->
                                            <td><input type="button" id="addmore" value="+" onclick="insRow()"/></td>
                                            <td align="center"><input type="button" id="delPOIbutton" value="-" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>

                                             <br /><p style="border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;"></p><br />
                                             <table border="0px" width="85%">
                                                 <tbody><tr>
                                                         <td width="105"><label class="description">No. of Students</label></td>
                                                         <td width="65"><input type="text" name=stu" size="5" maxlength="5"></input></td>
                                                         <td width="105"><label class="description">No. of Batches</label></td><td width="14"><input type="text" name="batch" size="5" maxlength="3"></input></td>
                                                     </tr>
                                                     <tr>


                                                     </tr>
                                                 </tbody>



                                             </table>     
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                            </form>

                            </table>    
                            </form>

                            </body>
                            </html>
```

Comment: Are You learning PHP 3 in 2013?

Comment: Also, its not the best idea to open a database connection 4 times in one script run. :-)

Comment: nice [SQL injection vulnerabilities](http://bobby-tables.com)...you should go study up on that before you try to work on any more code, or your server is going to get pwn3d. Your `if($!InsertQuery)` is redundant. if the query failed, the `or die(...)` will take care of it. and be VERY careful of that `empty()` call. it can burn you badly if you don't understand how to use it properly.

Answer (score -1):

Correct me if am wrong.
I didnt see any code to open a mysql database connection.

See this example.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","peter","abc123");
if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

// Create database
if (mysql_query("CREATE DATABASE my_db",$con))
{
   echo "Database created";
} else {
   echo "Error creating database: " . mysql_error();
}
?>
```

Before  inserting records using **mysql_query**, make sure that you opened a mysql db connection like above.

Comment: can u please help me in guiding me to how do i save that runtime generated table rows in mysql database using php